# Segmentation fault when I copy to binary file

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, token, binaryfiles

I got a homework . To copy from a text file that uses the format

```
name    birthday      street
NAME0;DAY/MONTH/YEAR;STREET0;
NAME1;DAY/MONTH/YEAR;STREET1;
NAME2;DAY/MONTH/YEAR;STREET2;
```

The information above and to sort by year . After I sorted , everything must be copied in a binary file .It gave me all the time Segmentation Fault . I think the problem is the `token` used to read every information from every line .

EDIT :
Using the debugger , I found that the line 167 when i = 4 causes the error . `strcpy(stud[i].day,token);`

EDIT :
I think the problem was in the input file . I re-created and now it's works .

```
void students_list(FILE *ifp , FILE *b_ifp)
{

    char line[150] ;
    char *token;
    int i = 0 , n , t = 0 ;

    memset(line,0,sizeof(line));

    ifp = fopen("students.txt","r");
    b_ifp = fopen("sorted.bin","wb");

    struct students
    {
        char name[20] , street[50] , year[5] , month[3] , day[3];

    };
    typedef struct students students;

    students stud[32], aux;

    while(fgets(linie,sizeof(line), ifp) != NULL)
    {

        token = strtok(line,";");
        strcpy(stud[i].name,token);

        token = strtok(NULL,"/");
        strcpy(stud[i].day,token);

        token = strtok(NULL,"/");
        strcpy(stud[i].month,token);

        token = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(stud[i].year,token);

        token = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(stud[i].street,token);

        i++;
    }

    n = i;
    while(t == 0)
    {
        t = 1;
        for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(stud[i].year,stud[i + 1].year) > 0)
            {
                aux = stud[i];
                stud[i] = stud[i + 1];
                stud[i + 1] = aux;
                t = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&stud[i], sizeof(stud[i]), 1, b_ifp);
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(b_ifp);
}
```

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger. At the very least it will immediately tell you which line is seg faulting.

Comment: Check for validity of your file pointers.

Comment: use `strtok_r` instead of `strtok`.

Comment: and figure out WHICH line is causing the segfault. you've got any number of array references that could be running off the end of the array.

Comment: `"MONTH"` is too small for `month[3]`.  Same for other fields.  If posted text is not the real input, post some real input.

Comment: I tried to print every token and it works but it doesn't copy to .bin file

Comment: Certain since code did `n = i - 1;`, the final `for()` should be `for(i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++)` else the last record is not save., but that does not answer OP's larger problem.

Comment: Good start on using the debugger. Now continue with your debugging session. Check the `token` value at that seg fault line you have identified. Is it valid and what you expect it to be at that time? Just trying to encourage you to learn to debug for yourself rather than turning to SO for help for what should be basic debugging.

Comment: Looks like you found the problem. One lesson you should draw from this is to always check the return values of functions - `strtok` return value in this case should be checked each time.

Comment: these lines: ` struct students
    {
        char name[20] , street[50] , year[5] , month[3] , day[3];

    };
    typedef struct students students;` should be in a header file or at the top, before `main()`, not buried within a function.

Comment: this line: `memset(line,0,sizeof(line));` is a complete waste of code.  Because the call to `fgets()` will overlay what where is in `line[]` (and terminate with a NUL char) each time it is called

Comment: when calling `fopen()` which can fail, always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this variable: `linie` does not exist in the posted code, you probably meant `line`.  When asking a runtime question,  copy/paste code that cleanly compiles.

Comment: to avoid an array overflow, this line: `while(fgets(linie,sizeof(line), ifp) != NULL)` should be (with spelling correction) `while(i < 32 && fgets(line,sizeof(line), ifp) != NULL)`

Comment: there are some 'magic' numbers in the posted code. like 32.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand and are a real headache when debugging and/or maintaining the code.  Suggest #define those numbers with meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this line: `if(strcmp(stud[i].year,stud[i + 1].year) > 0)`  due to the way the for()` statement is written, on the last iteration through the loop, `i+1` will be accessing the data past the end of the available data.  I.E. the `for()` needs to be corrected to stop one iteration earlier

Comment: this line: `aux = stud[i];` and this line: `stud[i + 1] = aux;` will not do what you expect.  Suggest `memcpy( &aux, &stud[i], sizeof(students));` and `memcpy( &stud[i+1], &aux, sizeof(students));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the problems could be several.  You can have a file with entries for more than `32` students.  You don't check the return codes from `strtok` (which can be `NULL`, if you don't feed the right format and there's no more fields) at first.  You could do all the stuff but refuse to add the record if `strtok` return value is `NULL` on input.  And check for array size (with something like `while(n < 32 && fgets(...` like one comment to the question suggests)

Something like:

```
char *name, *street, *year, *month, *day;

name   = strtok(line, ";");  if (!name) continue;
year   = strtok(NULL, "/");  if (!year) continue;
month  = strtok(NULL, "/");  if (!month) continue;
day    = strtok(NULL, ";");  if (!day) continue;
/* a line has a \n at the end, so we try to eliminate it if last ; not present */
street = strtok(NULL, ";\n"); if (!street) continue;
```

then, you need to comply for possible long fields, as `strcpy` doesn't and can lead you overwritting past the end of them.  As in:

```
strncpy(stud[i].name, sizeof stud[i].name, name);
strncpy(stud[i].day, sizeof stud[i].day, day);
...
```

This will check also to properly finalize each string with a null character in case it has to truncate the fields due to space (I think you have not provided space for it in the string fields of the `stud` structures)

finally, I'd suggest, as you read and sorted all data in core memory, just do only one `fwrite` call, like:

```
res = fwrite(stud, sizeof stud[0], n, b_ifp);
```

instead of looping through all the records.

Another question to debate is if you want the sorting being made on year numerically or lexicographically, as the years for sure don't span over the range `1950..2050` there's no problem, but suppose you have to order numbers in the range `1..1000`, as lexicographically, first comes `1`, then `10`, then `100`, then `1000`, then `101`, then `102`, ..., then `110`, `111`, `112`, ... `199`, `2`, `20`, `200`, `201`, ..., and I suppose this is not what you want.  It's better to convert the numbers to `int` s and do the sorting using relational operators.